Is there an option on Typesense to allow unlimited documents?
I recently moved from meilisearch to typesense on my Laravel app working with scout.
I've done all my configuration of models and search queries.
I was using a local instance of typesense which allowed me to import 3000 documents and I tought it was a normal behavior because I was working in local.
Before deploying my app, I installed a docker instance of meilisearch on my server and made some tests.
When I try to import documents with php artisan scout:import 'Model', I'm stuck at 3000 when my env is in local mode and 150000 when on development and production mode.
Do someone know if there is a parameter to change on my Laravel, on the typesense instance or anything else to import more documents ?
Here is my docker-compose.yml (which is the most common one):
version: '3.5'

services:
  typesense:
    image: typesense/typesense:27.0.rc21
    environment:
      TYPESENSE_DATA_DIR: /data
      TYPESENSE_API_KEY: myKey
    volumes:
      - /tmp/typesense-server-data:/data
    ports:
      - 8108:8108
    restart: 'always'

My scout config :
SCOUT_DRIVER=typesense
TYPESENSE_API_KEY=myKey
TYPESENSE_HOST=typesense.my-domain.com
TYPESENSE_PROTOCOL=https
TYPESENSE_PORT=443

And my scout model config :
'typesense' => [
        'client-settings' => [
            'api_key' => env('TYPESENSE_API_KEY', 'xyz'),
            'nodes' => [
                [
                    'host' => env('TYPESENSE_HOST', 'localhost'),
                    'port' => env('TYPESENSE_PORT', '8108'),
                    'path' => env('TYPESENSE_PATH', ''),
                    'protocol' => env('TYPESENSE_PROTOCOL', 'http'),
                ],
            ],
            'enable_nested_fields' => true,
            'nearest_node' => [
                'host' => env('TYPESENSE_HOST', 'localhost'),
                'port' => env('TYPESENSE_PORT', '8108'),
                'path' => env('TYPESENSE_PATH', ''),
                'protocol' => env('TYPESENSE_PROTOCOL', 'http'),
            ],
            'connection_timeout_seconds' => env('TYPESENSE_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_SECONDS', 2),
            'healthcheck_interval_seconds' => env('TYPESENSE_HEALTHCHECK_INTERVAL_SECONDS', 30),
            'num_retries' => env('TYPESENSE_NUM_RETRIES', 3),
            'retry_interval_seconds' => env('TYPESENSE_RETRY_INTERVAL_SECONDS', 1),
        ],
        'model-settings' => [
            Url::class => [
                'collection-schema' => [
                    'enable_nested_fields' => true,
                    'fields' => [
                        [
                            'name' => 'id',
                            'type' => 'string',
                        ],
                        [
                            'name' => 'url',
                            'type' => 'string',
                        ],
                        [
                            'name' => 'keywords',
                            'type' => 'object[]',
                            'fields' => [
                                [
                                    'name' => 'id',
                                    'type' => 'int32',
                                ],
                                [
                                    'name' => 'keyword',
                                    'type' => 'string',
                                    'sort' => true
                                ],
                                [
                                    'name' => 'volume',
                                    'type' => 'int32',
                                ],
                                [
                                    'name' => 'position',
                                    'type' => 'int32',
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'search-parameters' => [
                    'query_by' => 'keywords.keyword'
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],


You can store as many documents as you need in Typesense, as long as you have sufficient RAM to hold these documents in memory. The round number of documents limit you're referring to might be coming from somewhere outside of Typesense.

I have the same issue on different devices. For example, if I set my .env to local mode, i'm stuck at 3000 documents, on development or production mode to 15000 ducoments on a server with 64Gb of memory ?
